# My animation goes the wrong way (when I try to change a button's size)

Tags: ios, ipad, animation, button

I've got a bit of animation code that moves the pressed button, out of 9 available, to the centre of the screen:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^(void)
 {
     switch (correctNum) {
         case 1:
             [number1 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 60, 60)];
             break;
         case 2:
             [number2 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 60, 60)];
             break;
         case 3:
             [number3 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 60, 60)];
             break;
         case 4:
             [number4 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 60, 60)];
             break;
         case 5:
             [number5 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 60, 60)];
             break;
         case 6:
             [number6 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 60, 60)];
             break;
         case 7:
             [number7 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 60, 60)];
             break;
         case 8:
             [number8 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 60, 60)];
             break;
         case 9:
             [number9 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 60, 60)];
             break;
         default:
             break;
     }
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
 }];
```

Works fine, correct button smoothly moves across to the centre of the screen. But I wanted to make it so that the button grows to twice the size at the centre, so I changed code to:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^(void)
 {
     switch (correctNum) {
         case 1:
             [number1 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 120, 120)];
             break;
         case 2:
             [number2 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 120, 120)];
             break;
         case 3:
             [number3 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 120, 120)];
             break;
         case 4:
             [number4 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 120, 120)];
             break;
         case 5:
             [number5 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 120, 120)];
             break;
         case 6:
             [number6 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 120, 120)];
             break;
         case 7:
             [number7 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 120, 120)];
             break;
         case 8:
             [number8 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 120, 120)];
             break;
         case 9:
             [number9 setFrame:CGRectMake(482, 354, 120, 120)];
             break;
         default:
             break;
     }
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
 }];
```

Now when the code triggers, the button pressed jumps to the centre of the screen (no smooth animation) then smoothly moves back to its original position - effectively the reverse of what the code above did. The button doesn't change size, either.

Any idea why it's doing this? Or failing that, advice on how to make it do what I want it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, are you using auto layout? If you are, this code will not work correctly. With AutoLayout, you need to change the constraints rather than trying to move your view.

Now, as to your code:

I would suggest changing the center property of your view rather than the frame origin. Moving the center works even if a transform has been applied.

Then, to change the size, change the bounds size (will cause the button to re-draw itself at the larger size). You COULD change the button's transform as the others suggested, but that would scale the pixels rather than re-drawing, so it will look blocky (or blurry, depending). It should look better if you change the bounds.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. I did have auto layout enabled. After simply switching it off (shout at me if that's bad!) the app now works as expected.

Comment: Though as you pointed out it means that the image ends up off centre because of me using frame origin ....

Comment: Turned out that scaling the image using the CGAffine didn't end up making the image blocky - as long as the original image was scaled to the enlarged size. As the images aren't large to start with this was fine.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then you should accept it so others know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the width and height of the frame, keep the first example and change the transform of the button:

```
numberX.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2,2);
```

I can't explain why your second example doesn't work right, but if the first example works for moving the button to the center of the screen, keep that and use the button's transform property to enlarge it.

Comment: Thanks user2105505, but whilst auto layout is enabled, that just causes the image two grow without moving. However, combining turning off auto layout & using this transform does sort it out

Comment: btw CGAffineTranformMakeScale transforms the original image, so when the following animation returned the image to its original position it was tiny! Realised I needed to use CGAffineTransformScale.